# Hibernate Search is required javax.persistence.EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, hibernate-search

I'm trying make test application using Hibernate Search. I have note repository which
extend SimpleJpaRepository with required parameter `jakarta.persistence.EntityManager`. But when i try to create search session `Search.session(entityManager)` I get an error that the Search.session() need javax.persistence.EntityManager. So question is how can i create Search session using `jakarta.persistence.EntityManager`?

NoteRepository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
class NoteRepositoryImpl(
    private val entityManager: EntityManager,
) : SimpleJpaRepository<NoteEntity, Long>(NoteEntity::class.java, entityManager), NoteRepository {

    override fun search(query: String): List<NoteEntity> {
        val session = Search.session(entityManager)

        val result = session.search(NoteEntity::class.java)
            .where { it.match().fields("title", "tag", "content").matching(query) }
            .fetch(0, 100)
        return result.hits().map { it as NoteEntity }
    }
}
```

Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.22'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.7.22'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "1.7.22"
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen' version '1.7.22'
}

allOpen {
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.Embeddable")
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    implementation 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-mapper-orm:6.1.8.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-backend-lucene:6.1.8.Final'

    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.withType(KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Spring Boot 3, which is based on `jakarta.*` you'd need to  use a jakarta version of orm-mapper:

```
implementation 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-mapper-orm-jakarta:6.1.8.Final'
```

Comment: Changing the dependency to *-jakarta does not fix it for me.

Comment: what version of Hibernate Search do you have, and which dependencies do you have? and if your setup isn't exactly the same as in the OP question, maybe it's worth opening a different topic.

Comment: That's true, I tried to change my comment to be a bit more specific but the 5 minutes had passed already. I cannot reproduce my setup but switching to hibernate search 7.x solved all my issues without any workaround.